# Item Factor Analysis, Item Response Theory and Exploratory IRT

Tags: categorical-data, item-response-theory

I would be grateful if someone could explain the difference between Item Factor Analysis, Item Response Theory and Exploratory IRT. Any references especially for the exploratory IRT are welcome.

Nikos

Comment: possible answers are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118174/item-response-theory-vs-confirmatory-factor-analysis?rq=1) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215404/is-there-factor-analysis-or-pca-for-ordinal-or-binary-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)